# Refactoring: Finding a Common Abstraction

Tags: oop, refactoring

I've got this piece of legacy code which I'm trying to refactor at the moment:

```
    public class FileManger
    {
        private IFileReader _fileReader;
        private IFileWriter _fileWriter;

        public enum Mode { Read = 1, Write = 2 };

        public void Open( Mode mode)
        {
            if (mode == Mode.Read)
            {
                _fileReader = new FileReader();
            }
            else if (mode == Mode.Write)
            {
                _fileWriter = new FileWriter();
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to be able to replace this piece of code with a factory method and assign the returned to a common filed.

**so.. I'm trying to make it look like:**

```
public class FileManger
{
    private IFileHandler _fileHandler;

    public enum Mode { Read = 1, Write = 2 };

    public void Open(string fileName, Mode mode)
    {
        _fileHandler = Factory.CreateFileHandler(mode);
    }
 }
```

The problem I have is the two original interfaces IFileReader and IFileWriter, though they are quite closer in shape to each other, they have two completely different methods  string ReadLine(); and void WriteLine(string line); for which I could not find a common abstration.

Basically my refactoring goal is to make the IFileReader and IFileWriter interfaces look the same and use a common interface instead of two.

currently these interfaces look like this:

```
 public interface IFileReader : IDisposable
    {
        void OpenFileStream(string fileName);
        void Close();

        string ReadLine();
    }
```

and

```
public interface IFileWriter : IDisposable
    {

        void OpenFileStream(string fileName);
        void Close();

        void WriteLine(string line);
    }
```

could someone give me some suggestions on how I could go around achieving this?

Please let me know if you need any further clarifications, if I made it unclear to understand.

Comment: I don't think you should look for a generalization between IFileReader and IFileWriter. It looks like the one is exclusively for input, the other exclusively for output. So, I would not try to force them to be similar.

Comment: @Barth. Thanks for your comment. Do you see any other way I could improve the design of this code?

Comment: Hm... not for this snippet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see why you would like to use a common interface for such different operations, but assuming you have good reasons for that, I guess you could do something like this, where `line` would be read or written, depending on file mode:

```
public interface IFileAccessor : IDisposable
{
    void OpenFileStream(string fileName);
    void Close();
    void TransferLine(ref string line);
}
```